# pattern search in text strings in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I just want look for a pattern in a string. for example for this "abaxavabaabcabbc" string the app should print "abc" and "abbc". So, the pattern should have "abc" but the numbers of "b" are changing.
pattern => "abc" => the numbers of "b" are changeable.
And the programm should be in c++.

Comment: So you're only looking for a, followed by a least one b, followed by one c?

Comment: Do you know what "regular expressions" are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex_search instead of the iterator:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c064d5ef5aded77e)**

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::regex const pattern("ab+c");
    for (std::string const text :
         {
             "abaxavabaabcabbc",
         }) //
    {
        std::smatch match;
        for (auto it = text.cbegin(), e = text.cend();
             std::regex_search(it, e, match, pattern); it = match[0].second) {
            std::cout << "Match: " << match.str() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Match: abc
Match: abbc
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one answer to this question. You MUST use a `std::regex`. Regular expressions are exactly made for this purpose.

C++ supports also regular expressions. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

The regex "ab+c" will match all strings starting with an "a", having one or more "b" and end with a "c"

See the following very short program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

const std::regex re{ R"(ab+c)" };
using Iter = std::sregex_token_iterator;

int main() {
    const std::string test{ "abaxavabaabcabbc" };

    std::copy(Iter(test.begin(), test.end(), re), Iter(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

This program will iterate over all matched patterns and copy them to `std::cout`

Comment: I would never say he MUSTS use `std::regex` for it. For this purpose it might be quite slow (especially compile time will be way longer using regular expressions) and defining his own function which would recursively look first for such expression might be faster. Still, using built-in regex is the quickest way to look for it.